# PHP / CI: Facebook Connect seems to use my site session instead of Facebook session

Tags: codeigniter, facebook, redirect

I've got a CodeIgniter project using the Facebook Connect "official" PHP implementation. For the most part it works fine, except for when a user first allows permissions.  I've traced the problem deep into the provide facebook.php, the `getSession()` function:

```
public function getSession() {
if (!$this->sessionLoaded) {
  $session = null;
  $write_cookie = true;

  // try loading session from signed_request in $_REQUEST
  $signedRequest = $this->getSignedRequest();
  if ($signedRequest) {
    // sig is good, use the signedRequest
    $session = $this->createSessionFromSignedRequest($signedRequest);
  }

  // try loading session from $_REQUEST
  if (!$session && isset($_REQUEST['session'])) {
    $session = json_decode(
      get_magic_quotes_gpc()
        ? stripslashes($_REQUEST['session'])
        : $_REQUEST['session'],
      true
    );
    /* HERE IS WHERE IT GOES WRONG */
    $session = $this->validateSessionObject($session);
    }
```

My comment in the code is where things go wrong. The if block above gets evaluated successfully, but the code inside the `json_decode()` function parameter returns the string:

```
a:4:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"********";s:10:"ip_address";s:13:"********";s:10:"user_agent";s:50:"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2";s:13:"last_activity";i:1304286136;}edc0c222265e0a16c0f3fe8a96decf77
```

This looks like my site session, rather than the facebook session that it's trying to access (which I can see in the URL). Why is this happening? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else hits this particular snag, I'll post how I solved it:

Just change `$_REQUEST` to `$_GET`

My guess is that CodeIgniter somehow puts your session information into the $_REQUEST array... why this happens is beyond me, but it solved the problem for me. Hope it helps!